# Root directory of Cygwin, with regard to shared folder and the place of SVN

Tags: svn, cygwin

I have a dual virtual systems: `Windows` and `Ubuntu`, which share a folder. Under `Windows`, the access to the shared folder is via `Z:\SharedFolder\`. Under `Ubuntu`, its access is `/mnt/hgfs/SharedFolder`.

There is a subsubsub folder `Programs` within `SharedFolder` where I put many codes, and most of them are managed via `svn` with a remote server.

I just installed `Cygwin` under `Windows` in order to generate binary for Windows, I set `C:\cygwin` as `Root Directory`. But it seems that within a Cygwin terminal, I could not go to manage files outside `C:\cygwin`, for instance files in `Z:\SharedFolder\...\Programs\`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

That complicates the issue, because I would like to develop codes in `Z:\SharedFolder\...\Programs\`. The advantages are to avoid copy-past, and be able to manage them via `svn`.

Does anyone have a good idea for the `Root Directory`of `Cygwin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access Windows drives, use `/cygdrive/<driveletter>` where `<driveletter>` is the drive's name on Windows . Cygwin has problems with using the `:` character in pathnames (and Windows-style paths in general), so you must use the `/cygdrive/` format in some contexts.

http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive